# How to clear APC cache without crashing Apache?

Tags: php, performance, caching, apc

If APC stores a lot of entries, clearing them crashes httpd.

> *If apc_clear_cache('user') takes longer than phps max_execution_time
>   the script calling apc_clear_cache
>   will be terminated by php before the
>   clearing-operation is finished. this
>   seems to leave some handles or sth.
>   that will prevent apache from closing
>   it's processes.*

(http://pecl.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=13445)

Is there some other quick but safe way of bulk cleanup of APC cache?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove the time limit on a script you're running (as long as you don't run php in safe mode)

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

This will remove the time limit for the script

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php for more details

Comment: I just noticed that this was the suggested workaround for the problem in the link you posted :)

Answer (score 5):

You can also gracefully restart apache and it will reload with a clean APC.

Comment: is this a valid approach in a production environment when one would gracefully restart apache after a new deployment version of an app?

Comment: it's acceptable if you don't care about a second of down time.

Comment: _Gracefully_ restarting Apache doesn’t cause any downtime at all, not even a second.

Comment: So three people agree with me but none up-voted my answer... hmmm :(