# Symfony2 autoloader found file but did not find class

Tags: php, symfony, autoloader

I am trying to install symfony2 without vendors and I keep getting the following error when running app_dev.php:

```
RuntimeException: The autoloader expected class "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event" to be defined in file "/var/www/caremonk/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Event.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.
```

I've installed the correct files and vendors via: 
     php composer.phar update
     php composer.phar install

I've also checked the file that Symfony2 was complaining about and the file's contents are:

```
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of the Symfony package.
 *
 * (c) Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher;

/**
 * Event is the base class for classes containing event data.
 *
 * This class contains no event data. It is used by events that do not pass
 * state information to an event handler when an event is raised.
 *
 * You can call the method stopPropagation() to abort the execution of
 * further listeners in your event listener.
 *
 * @author  Guilherme Blanco <guilhermeblanco@hotmail.com>
 * @author  Jonathan Wage <jonwage@gmail.com>
 * @author  Roman Borschel <roman@code-factory.org>
 * @author  Bernhard Schussek <bschussek@gmail.com>
 *
 * @api
 */
class Event
{
   // Some more code
}
```

This is a standard symfony2 class that I have not touched, so I'm a little lost on what I need to do. How can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ran into a similar issue last night. Disabling and re-enabling APC seemed to do the trick.

Comment: I just restarted apache, and for whatever reason that did the trick. Your suggestion lead me to do so, thanks!

Comment: Great! Some more googling led to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144350/do-we-need-to-restart-apache-apc-after-new-version-deployment-of-app